# EventHubs architecture

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I have a file service (WCF) writing file info to an on-prem DB and saving the file to the Azure blob storage. We are thinking of updating this process to publish an event to Azure EventHubs. Some team members are saying that everything should be reversed if the event can't be posted but I think we should just re-try in case something happens while publishing the event, so the user doesn't have to re upload the file.

What would you do?

Comment: What is the reasoning to introduce the eventhub, what is the use case?

Comment: If you're just looking to emit a notification that data has been uploaded, seems like Event Grid may be a better choice here.

Comment: @PeterBons Right now after the data is stored in the DB, a message is posted to RabbiMQ for further processing or when the same record/file is updated. EventHubs is supposed to eventually replace RabbiMQ.

Comment: @JesseSquire the main difference seems to be that EventGrid works more like in a pub-sub model? I couldn't really understand how that would be different from an EventHubs consumer posting another message to a different EventHubs after some processing of the file or file info

Comment: Event Grid is a push-based model that calls into your webhook when a blob is available.   Event Hubs is a pull-based model where your application needs to continually poll to look for data.   For Event Grid, you do not have to publish an event that says "a blob is available" - Azure is responsible for it.   For Event Hubs, your application is responsible for publishing an event and, therefore, has another point of failure to contend with.